# How to format date in Bootstrap template?

Tags: mysql, node.js, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to listing the date on bootstrap table from database.
My data base date value is :

[image]

But After redirecting the value to html page it shows like this.

[image]

Why this is happening?

My html code is

```
<td style="word-break: break-all;"><%=schedulerList[i].to_date %></td>
<td style="word-break: break-all;">  <%=schedulerList[i].from_date %></td>
```

But after listing it gives me in another format.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). Bootstrap is for CSS mainly and you have to take care of formatting stuff yourself...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Node.js, you can install a library for conversion.

**Installation**

```
$ npm install dateformat
$ dateformat --help
```

**Usage**

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();

// Basic usage
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

See documentation [node-dateformat](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat)

Or can format with javascript:

> The [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method parses a string representation of a date, and
>   returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC
>   or NaN if the string is unrecognised or, in some cases, contains
>   illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

**Direct call:**

```
Date.parse(dateString)
```

**Implicit call:**

```
new Date(dateString)
```

Or use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or another lib...

Finally, you can also format in your SQL/QUERY if you feel better.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(from_date, '%a %d %b %Y %h::%i:%S %p') AS format_date
```

[See DATE_FORMAT](https://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)